# Silverlight Rich text editor - extract as String?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

Is there a silverlight rich text editor out there who would enable me to extract the made text as a string so I could save it in a db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard RTB in Silverlight has a `public string Xaml { get; set; }` property.